# No me funciona el live server vscode

Tags: vscode, vscode-live-server

Hola estoy teniendo problemas para abrir mis archivos con live server, me muestra un error como si fuera de red, yo al momento no utilizo proxy ni nada, les paso foto del error que creen que seria?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @rpaillao no tengo mucho mas que agregar, es un error de red que no entiendo porque me salta si no utilizo ningún proxy

Comment: si es algo de red podrias intentar con nmap , para ver si llegas al server y ver si este tiene el puerto correspondiente abierto.